# How to initialize (and Seed) two Entity Framework dbcontext objects?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have two dbcontexts in my code:

1. AppIdentityDbContext
2. AppDataDbContext

The first one (AppIdentityDbContext) is your vanilla dbcontext you get when you create a WebApi application and you indicate you need local authentication. It creates tables AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles, etc. By default this context is named ApplicationDbContext but I renamed it.

The second dbcontext (AppDataDbContext) is the context I intend to use to deal with the application's data (everything except AspNet.Identity data).

Each of these db contexts point to two different database files (LocalDb right now)

My Global.asax file looks like the code below:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    // initialize user database
    Database.SetInitializer(new InitializeAppIdentityDbContext());
    AppIdentityDbContext identityContext = new AppIdentityDbContext();
    identityContext.Database.Initialize(true);

    // initialize data domain database with sample data
    Database.SetInitializer(new InitializeAppDataDbContext());
    AppDataDbContext dataContext = new AppDataDbContext();
    dataContext.Database.Initialize(true);
}
```

InitializeAppIdentityDbContext seeds/creates --through the use of UserManager, several ApplicationUser instances. These users get populated in AspNetUsers table.

Similarly I am trying to seed AppDataDbContext and have code there to do just that.

The problem is that I get an error when line below attempts to execute which is the very last line:

```
dataContext.Database.Initialize(true);
```

The error says:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

SampleApi.DataAccess.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
SampleApi.DataAccess.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.
```

This is puzzling to me since the second db context (AppDataDbContext) does not have any models that reference any of the AspNetIdentity stuff being mentioned (IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserLogins, etc.). The models there are my own classes for the application.

Anyhow, I am sure I am violating something in how I'm going about initializing these two dbcontexts but have no idea what the proper way is to accomplish it. So if you are here, thank you for bearing with me and reading my message. Any ideas of what I should try?

Many thanks,

-Alex

Comment: I would recommend specifying the initializer as either a `DbConfiguration` or via the `<entityFramework>` node in your `web.config`. Using the global initializer for two contexts is going to be problematic.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't combine the two databases? and with your second custom database, you inherit from the identity dbcontext, so it becomes one single context